# android app interact with system bluetooth pairing dialog

Tags: android, bluetooth, system, pairing

I am researching my first attempt to write an android app.  I basically just need a "dumb" app that runs on the device and looks for the Bluetooth pairing pop-up request and selects the "Pair" option.

I have found a lot of examples of this when the application I'd be writing is the one instantiating the pairing, but in this case, it's not - it's more of an "out-of-band" scenario.  A device will initiate a pairing request with the phone & and app this "dumb" app would be running on.  All I want to do is have this app detect when that happens and accept the pairing requests so I don't have to constantly do this manually.

I know there are automation frameworks that can do this, but that is such overkill for a what seems to be a simple task  - just sit there and every # seconds (maybe 15) do a quick check for the pairing pop-up dialog and press pair

Is this possible?